# Python ZeroDivisionError

Tags: python, exception

I know what this error means, but I don't know why I get it in my program, I can't seem to make my program work.

This is the error I get:

```
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Here's a little snippet from my code:

```
calc_A = round((math.log(y2) - math.log(y1))/(math.log(x2) - math.log(x1)), -1)
calc_B = round(y1/pow(calc_A, x1), -1)
```

Here are the values used:

- **x1:** 1
- **y1:** 10
- **x2:** 2
- **y2:** 20

Comment: you need to change -1 to 1 !

Comment: @Kasra: Not unless he wants to round to 1/10ths. The `ndigits` parameter should simply be dropped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`calc_A` is `0.0`, and `0` raised to any power (besides 0) remains `0`.

Therefore, `y1/0` raises this exception.

Your problem is that you told [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) to round to the nearest multiple of `10` (because you set the `ndigits` parameter to `-1`).

```
>>> x1=1
>>> y1=10
>>> x2=2
>>> y2=20
>>> math.log(x2) - math.log(x1)
0.6931471805599453
>>> math.log(y2) - math.log(y1)
0.693147180559945
>>> (math.log(y2) - math.log(y1))/(math.log(x2) - math.log(x1))
0.9999999999999996
>>> round(_, -1)
0.0
>>> round(0.99)
1.0
```

Comment: But when I print out calc_A, it says that it's 0,9999999995 and assuming I used the round function properly, it should round up to 1 and not down to 0. I think I'm not using the round function properly, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I removed the -1 and it's working now. I got the result I wanted.

Comment: Yes, `round(n, -1)` rounds `n` to the next multiple of `10`.

Comment: Actually, 0 raised to 0 power is 1.

Answer (score 1):

That error happends because of the round function with a negative precision digit.

Check this.

```
number = 1.23456
print(round(number)) #1
print(round(number, 0)) # 1.0
print(round(number, 1)) # 1.2
print(round(number, 2)) # 1.23
print(round(number, 3)) # 1.235
print(round(number, -1)) # 0.0  
print(round(1234, -1)) #1230.0
```